# How to improve scrolling speed of my table which has multiple stackviews in it?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableView` which has multiple `UIStackView` as items in it. In those `UIStackView` I add colored squares as subviews. The problem is, it heavily slows down the vertical scrolling.

How do I improve scrolling performance?

Here is how scrolling looks:
https://gfycat.com/DentalContentIndigowingedparrot

Here is the source code:
https://github.com/Cook10/StackTableProblem

Comment: Is it fair to ask why you can't just use a collection view to do all of this?

Comment: Because this code is done  to demonstrate the poor scrolling performance. In my actual project there are more items in cells so I have to use UITableView.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the point of reusing cells. Your code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    addStacksToTableCell(cell.stack1)
    addStacksToTableCell(cell.stack2)
    addStacksToTableCell(cell.stack3)
    addStacksToTableCell(cell.stack4)

    return cell
}
```

everytime you scroll down and a new cell is displayed, you are removing all views inside it (400 views) and your are creating new views (400 views), triggering the expensive layout and rerendering mechanism.

That happens every time your scroll.

This completely defeats the purpose of reusing cells. It's the same as creating a new cell every time.

Instead, create the views only once and when reusing the cells, only update the color of the internal views. Don't recreate views just to change their color.

Using some very naive changes:

Add to your cell:

```
var createdViews: Bool = false
var views1: [UIView] = []
var views2: [UIView] = []
var views3: [UIView] = []
var views4: [UIView] = []
```

Then replace your controller methods with:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    if !cell.createdViews {
        cell.views1 = addStacksToTableCell(cell.stack1)
        cell.views2 = addStacksToTableCell(cell.stack2)
        cell.views3 = addStacksToTableCell(cell.stack3)
        cell.views4 = addStacksToTableCell(cell.stack4)

        cell.createdViews = true
    } else {
        // only update the views
        cell.views1.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.random() }
        cell.views2.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.random() }
        cell.views3.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.random() }
        cell.views4.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.random() }
    }

    return cell
}

func addStacksToTableCell(_ stack: UIStackView) -> [UIView] {

    stack.removeAllArrangedSubviews()

    var views: [UIView] = []

    for i in 0..<ITEMS{
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.backgroundColor = UIColor.random()
        stack.addArrangedSubview(image)

        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)

        image.addConstraints([width,height])

        views.append(image)
    }

    return views
}
```

Comment: How do I reuse the cells?

Comment: @TheCook Added a sample implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% connected to this particular case, but another way to improve cell scrolling is :

In iOS, you can use Auto Layout to define the height of a table view cell; however, the feature is not enabled by default.

Normally, a cell’s height is determined by the table view delegate’s **tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:** method. To enable self-sizing table view cells, you must set the table view’s **rowHeight** property to **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**. You must also assign a value to the **estimatedRowHeight** property. As soon as both of these properties are set, the system uses Auto Layout to calculate the row’s actual height.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Next, lay out the table view cell’s content within the cell’s content view. To define the cell’s height, you need an unbroken chain of constraints and views (with defined heights) to fill the area between the content view’s top edge and its bottom edge. If your views have intrinsic content heights, the system uses those values. If not, you must add the appropriate height constraints, either to the views or to the content view itself.

Additionally, try to make the estimated row height as accurate as possible. The system calculates items such as the scroll bar heights based on these estimates. The more accurate the estimates, the more seamless the user experience becomes.

Wish you all the best.